# Loop last error getting entries

Tags: templating, loop

Craft 4

```
Key "last" for array with keys "parent, index0, index, first" does not exist.
```

When using

```
{% if loop.last %}
```

Data is there and printing out a menu but cannot seem to get the last loop.

Comment: Hey can you give the full code for this. I tried on my end I can run loop.last without error.

Answer (score 11):

Updated answer: make sure your for loop is calling `.all()` and `{{loop.last}}` should work.

<strike>You'll need to use `{% if loop|last %}`. This has changed in Twig 3 (which i guess Craft 4 is now using).</strike>

See: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/last.html